# Impact of installing compromised packages

Tags: security, package-management

Imagine one of the packages you want to install (say via `apt`, `dnf` or some other package manager) was compromised, i.e. adversarially modified, and did get into the (official) repository of your Linux distribution undetected. Which, given that there are tens of thousands of packages even in the official repositories of various Linux distributions, does not seem to be too unlikely (especially for more uncommon packages).

In such a case, I was wondering about the security implications at installation time. I first suspected this to a major security issue, in particular because package installation has to be done with root privileges typically. However, I am unsure about the internals of the various package managers, and I could image that a package manager could "simple copy" the application files to be installed into the corresponding directories -- without actually executing any compromised code. In the later case, maybe "only" an unprivileged user which does execute the installed application at a later point in time is compromised, while the system or other user's data remains safe as long as the compromised application is not used.

I would highly appreciate if somebody could explain how this work under the hood. In particular, I would be interested to get some insight on how this works for Ubuntu/Debians's `apt` and Fedora's `dnf` package managers (the main ones I use). If the default behavior of these package manager allows for arbitrary scripts to be executed during installation, I would also be very interested if there are some options to change this behavior, or if there are other package manager which are more secure in under the described circumstances.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: apt-get (and friends) has been around for many years. If you really want to mess things up, why not just distribute a dodgy kernel?

Comment: Just FYI: https://itvision.altervista.org/linux-myths-series-linux-doesnt-need-an-antivirus.html

Comment: If a rogue package maintainer in any distro wants to own every user who uses their packages, they absolutely can do it. Now, as to why it hasn't yet happened - I've no idea but again it's possible. But then again we've recently had a whole university computer department willingly and knowingly pushing bad patches to the Linux kernel. They've been detected and the damage has been averted but the system of trust in Linux is not particularly failproof.

Answer (score 4):

Both RPM and DEB packages can run anything they want during the installation process. Yes, the installation process is mostly about copying files, but sometimes packages need to interact with the system (updating various caches, for example when installing fonts) so the package can run various commands/scripts during installation (or upgrade or removal). Packages can also enable/start systemd services they contain. If you want some examples how this works, check [Fedora scriptlets documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/) or [package maintainer scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html#) for Debian. There is also [this interesting LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/770784/) about this potential risk.

When installing RPM packages manually using `rpm` you can specify `--noscripts` to turn scriptlets off and you can use `noscripts` transaction flag with `dnf`, but that isn't really helping with compromised packages.

But even without these various ways to run scripts during installation, they can simply replace existing system binaries, services and config files with a "compromised" version and get the same result. So yes, a compromised package (or a package installed from an unknown/untrusted source) can be a huge problem.

Packaging for distributions is mostly based on trust -- with Fedora [you need to prove you are able to create and maintain a package](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Join_the_package_collection_maintainers), but after that nothing really blocks packagers from pushing malicious  content. There are some automated tests (and optional manual testing from other community members) for every new version which includes a ClamAV scan so there is some protection, but I don't think this can cover everything and as you said, there are thousands of packages in the official repo.

Comment: In Fedora, manual testing isn’t even required — it can help add karma to get a package into stable faster, but it will get there eventually. (Debian doesn’t even have manual testing in a centralised way.)